# Is it true that each prime number $p_k=p_j+p_{j+1} \pm 1, \ 2j+1<k$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that each prime number $p_k=p_j+p_{j+1} \pm 1, \ 2j+1<k, \ j=0,1,2...$?

Comment: some Glodbach's conjecture if you move 1 to the left. yes?

Comment: Is $p_j$  the $j$th prime number?

Comment: Not true for $p_k\le 5$

Comment: yes it's $j$-th prime, $j=0,1,2...$ and $k$ is unknown index of result prime

Comment: You seem to be asking if each prime is one more or one less than the sum of two consecutive smaller primes.  The result is false for the primes $2$ and $3$ and $5$.

Comment: $19 + 23 + 1 < 47 < 23 + 29 -1$, $43 + 47 + 1 < 97 < 47 + 53 -1$

Comment: Also, $p_n\sim n\log n$, hence we need $2j\log j\approx k\log k$, which makes $\frac kj\approx 2\frac{\log j}{\log k}\ne 2$

Comment: 3+5-1=7;
5+7-1=11;
5+7+1=13;
7+11-1=17;
7+11+1=19;
and so on

Comment: $89,97$ are consecutive primes. $89+97=186$ and $185$ is divisible by $5$ so $185$ is not prime and $187$ is divisible by $11$ so $187$ is not prime. There may exist smaller counterexamples.

Comment: One more statement: Is the sum of two sequent primes plus/minus one prome?

Comment: @user236182 Your counterexample is for "given $j$, tehre exists $k$ ...", while the OP asks for $given $k$, there exists $j$ ...". And for that, Daniel Fischer has given a counterexample

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It is not clear what OP meant exactly; from the comment he made just before mine it seems that OP wants to know if at least one of the two numbers -- the sum of any two consecutive primes plus and minus one, is prime.

Comment: The question is closed now

Comment: Sum of consequent primes +/- 1 doesnt returns prime, ty everybody for discussion :)